# Pure Java app on Glassfish?

Tags: java, jakarta-ee, glassfish

I may be barking up the wrong tree here -- it's relatively easy to wrap a vanilla Java app in a daemon/service -- but it'd be really helpful for deployment if we could push pure Java apps onto a Glassfish server and have them start up automatically.

We use JMS to connect this app to several other beans living on the Glassfish server. We are actually using glassfish to "deploy" it to the production machine, but it doesn't start automatically. Have been looking into JCA, but it doesn't seem like quite what I'm looking for.

Thanks!

Comment: welcome to the 'enterprise' side of java. :)

Comment: I don't know about Glassfish but WebSphere and Weblogic have the concept of startup beans that are started when the enterprise app is started.

Comment: @DMKing: glassfish runs on OSGi and HK2, both having the concepts of modules (bundles in OSGi, don't know what they're called in HK2), which can be started directly, but I don't know how to configure Glassfish to actually start them.

Comment: What do you mean by *"start up automatically"*? What do you expect it to do?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If your 'pure Java app' is packaged as .war you could add a [ServletContextListner](http://java.sun.com/products/servlet/2.3/javadoc/javax/servlet/ServletContextListener.html) to your app that gets called when the application is loaded and that performs the starup of the application...

Comment: +1 this is pretty simple, and will work perfectly well. We have used this  method for starting up services like Lucene, in the instance where we build and use an in memory index.